# Programming on android, error with "super(context);"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem with my program. I use the book "Beginning Android Tablet Games Programming". In this book, using Eclipse, Java JDK and the Android SDK Manager.

```
com.gameproject.grafika package;

android.content.Context import;
android.graphics.Bitmap import;
android.graphics.BitmapFactory import;
android.graphics.Canvas import;
android.graphics.Color import;
android.view.View import;

public class GameView {
    public GameView (Context context) {
        super (context);
    }

    public void OnDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap star = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getResources (), R.drawble.gracz);
        canvas.drawColor (Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap (star, 10, 10, null);
    }
}
```

Eclipse highlights `super (context)` and `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources () R.drawble.gracz)`

What could be the reason?
Please, quick help and sorry for my English.

Comment: Eclipse generally tells you the reason- hover your cursor over the highlight and it should provide a message telling you what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be that you aren't extending anything, but you intended to.

`super(context)` calls through to the parent class' constructor. However, `GameView` doesn't extend any classes, and thus there is no parent class to call.

Similarly, you haven't defined a `getResources()` method, and since you aren't extending anything, no parent class is providing a `getResources()` method. Thus `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawble.gracz)` isn't going to work either.

From the looks of this class, you meant to extend the `View` class.